# New badge for answering N questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

This has nothing to do with the fact I've attempted to answer nearly 1000 questions, but based purely on that fact ( :) ), should there be a badge for answering certain thresholds?

Joking aside, there are many people who put a lot of their own time and despite not getting a great deal of my answers right, it doesn't take it away..

The badges are a bit of fun, I understand that, but, I think the site needs a good team of answering folk, so little awards do help.

Comment: These already kinda exist in the form of tag badges.

Comment: @Dave - The only way I would even agree there should be a badge for answering a ton of questions is if those answers also had to have a significant postive vote count ( i.e. greater than 5 ).  Most of your answers don't have a single upvote.

Answer (score 12):

I don't think so. It may just end up promoting people to answer questions with more useless answers.

The current badges for answering questions, such as ["Great Answer"](https://meta.superuser.com/help/badges/25/great-answer) promote quality over quantity, which I think is more oriented towards SE's goal than just having a ton of answers

Comment: This suggests more answers are rubbish compared to those relevant :-). Also,  1k answers takes time and effort,  hardly the work of people who want to prove rubbsih answers for the sake of a badge

Comment: @Dave you'd be surprised what people will do in attempts to get a virtual badge that has no use beyond bragging rights.

Comment: @Dave It promotes the sort of behaviour that people use on console games to gain achievements by the laziest (or indeed most underhand) means possible so in this case I agree with nhinkle and Simon

Comment: A bunch of crude is still a bunch of crude go for the gems. Quality answers are those gems